# Make List items unfocusable

Tags: android

The default behavior of a list when one of it's items is touched is for that item to gain focus while it is being touched. I need a way to make the list items unfocusable ,so that when they are being touched  , nothing should happen.

Comment: This does not seem to be a viable solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `ListView` I used the property:

```
"android:listSelector = @drawable/my_selector"
```

Here, `my_selector.xml` contains the definition of a selector with no `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:focusable="false"` to your `ListView.

Comment: Tried .Items still gain focus !

Comment: so i will have to try myself, till that check this also android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```